# Is it mass or density that curves space time?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, spacetime

According to General Relativity, any heavy object can curve spacetime significantly. But then black holes, which have the mass of a star, have much higher gravitational forces. So can we say that it is the high density of the black hole that has to do with the curved space around it?

Comment: have you studied the Schwarzschild radius? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_radius

Comment: A black hole does not have a well defined concept of density. For example, the volume inside a Schwarzschild event horizon, as observed from outside, is zero: “*There is zero volume inside the black hole in any Schwarzschild time slice of a Schwarzschild black hole spacetime.*” - https://arxiv.org/pdf/0801.1734.pdf  (p. 6). Also, there also is no matter in a black hole, only vacuum. The mass of a black hole is not the mass of matter (there is no matter), but refers to the energy of the empty curved space everywhere outside the horizon. Thus your question is not well defined.

Answer (score 5):

On the left side of Einstein’s field equations for General Relativity is the Einstein curvature tensor $G^{\mu\nu}$. On the right side is the [energy-momentum-stress tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor) $T^{\mu\nu}$ of all non-gravitational “stuff”: matter, radiation, Higgs field, etc. The 16 components of $T^{\mu\nu}$ represent the density and flow (or “flux”, in 3 directions) of energy and momentum.

Einstein’s equations state that the two tensors are simply *proportional*:

$$G^{\mu\nu}=\frac{8\pi G}{c^4}T^{\mu\nu}.$$

(The constant of proportionality involves Newton’s gravitational constant $G$ and the speed of light $c$, as one would expect for a theory of *relativistic gravity*.)

So, based on the relationship between the two tensors, it is common to say that spacetime curvature is “caused by” the density and flow of energy and momentum. (Note: Another word for “flow of momentum” is “pressure”. Pressure gravitates!)

Suppose we are talking about a collection of atoms and we want to know how they gravitate. In addition to knowing their masses and their locations, as in Newtonian gravity, in General Relativity we also need to take into account their *velocities*, because this motion affects the energy flow, the momentum density, and the momentum flow. Some people call these gravity-of-motion effects [gravitomagnetism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitoelectromagnetism).

Talking about just mass or “density” (density of *what*?) curving spacetime is common in popular introductions to General Relativity, but it’s not the whole story. $T^{\mu\nu}$ is the whole story about what “causes” curvature. So the next step in learning about this would be to read the Wikipedia article I linked to, which goes into detail about this tensor.

Note: I am taking the liberty of not bothering to distinguish between the components of a tensor and the tensor itself. Mathematicians hate this, but physicists do it frequently; entire textbooks on General Relativity, such as Weinberg’s, have been written this way. Today, it is somewhat old-fashioned as physicists increasingly adopt the mathematicians’ more abstract and often component-free notations, which do a better job of conveying the *geometric* nature of the physical quantities. I have also ignored the question of a cosmological constant term, and whether to put it on the left side with the curvature or incorporate it into $T^{\mu\nu}$ as “dark energy”.

Comment: Typical black holes, such as Schwarzschild or Kerr, are Ricci flat vacuum solutions meaning their stress-energy tensor is zero everywhere, so the gravitational equation simply is: $$R_{ab}=0$$ Black hole spacetimes are NOT curved by stress-energy. Also, General Relativity is a classical theory, so stress-energy does not include the quantum Higgs field.